# Open video with html5 from assets

Tags: java, android, html

I have an app that has HTML and mp4 files. I play these mp4 video files with the `<video>` tag in the HTML code. I can do it successfully only when the mp4 files are in the sdcard, but when I add the mp4 files to the assets or rest folder the videos can not play.
I read all videos in the assets folder (*.mp4) and copy these files to:

/data/data/packaganame/

My code to copy from assets to the "/data/data/packaganame/" folder is:

```
InputStream isVideo = null;
isVideo = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("video.mp4");
File fl = new File("/data/data/packaganame/videoout.mp4");
bufEcrivain = new BufferedOutputStream((new FileOutputStream(fl)));
VideoReader = new BufferedInputStream(isVideo);
byte[] buff = new byte[32 * 1024];
int len;
while( (len = VideoReader.read(buff)) > 0 ){
    bufEcrivain.write(buff,0,len);
}
bufEcrivain.flush();
bufEcrivain.close();
```

I execute this code for each video, and I don't get any exception. But when I try play the video, I get: "can not play video".

My HTML code is correct because it works fine when the `<video>` tag read from sdcard:

```
<video onclick="this.play();" 
       width="308" height="288" 
       autobuffer="autobuffer" controls="controls"
       tabindex="0">
  <source src="videoout.mp4">
</video>
```

My videos and my HTML files are in the same directory.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

try copying mp4 from resources like this:

```
android.content.res.Resources isVideo = somename.mContext.getResources();
```

with:

```
InputStream VideoReader = isVideo .openRawResource(R.raw.resources);
```

Comment: Sorry. I tried read from res/raw too, i used this :


isVideo = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.video);


But i get the same result : "can not play video"

Comment: Sorry. I tried read from res/raw too, i used this :


isVideo = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.video);


But i get the same result : "can not play video"